# IsolatedIsolatedStorageException in WPF application when creating/opening a db4o database?

Tags: c#, wpf, db4o

My code snippet:

```
using (var db = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(@"c:\temp\db4o\my.data"))
{
    ...
}
```

throws the following exception

> An exception of type
>   'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to determine application identity of
>   the caller.

It seems that db4o is using the IsolatedStorage, I don't know why as my application is WPF. Can someone give me a hint?